# Am I still limited to gigabit speed if the file transfer is happening between same VLAN on the same physical ethernet port and same host machine?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, switch, vlan

Consider the following:

Gigabit Switch port16 configured to have native network of VLAN10 (192.168.10.x) and tagged VLAN20 (192.168.20.x) and VLAN30. This port is plugged into proxmox machine.

Proxmox host will get 192.168.10.x IP address and I will create 2 Container and 1 VM inside proxmox, all CT/VM is set to VLAN20, so in summary.

1st Container installed with Frigate (NVR) -> 192.168.20.xx
2nd Container installed with qbittorrent -> 192.168.20.xx
VM installed with Openmediavault (NAS) -> 192.168.20.xx

And all these Container and VM will share the same SSD installed inside the proxmox machine. Now my question is

1. If I use qbittorrent to save the downloaded file directly to Openmediavault, am I limited to gigabit speed?
2. Similar to question 1. If I use Frigate NVR to save recorded video directly to Openmediavault, will the traffic leave the machine to the physical switch and go back to the same physical cable?
3. If I transfer file from proxmox host to one of the container/VM, will the traffic leave the machine to the physical switch? Since Proxmox and container/VM has different VLAN/subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traffic within the same VLAN will not leave the host and won't reach the physical interface (except for some broadcast protocol packets like ARP). It will be completely directed by the bridge (vmbr), which is actually the virtual ethernet switch in this case. Your VMs are plugged into this switch which has no hardware speed cap, so sky is your limit here.

The traffic between VLANs may or may not leave the host. It depends on where the inter-VLAN router is. If it's a VM on this host too, the traffic will go through your virtual switch twice (or through two virtual switches, depending on the use of vlan-aware bridges), but still not leave the host and not be limited by the interface speed. If the router is not physically on the same host, the traffic will leave the host and then reenter it, so the physical link will limit the speed.